# Web Service in PHP - just another PHP file/url?

Tags: php, web-services

I am tasked with making a web service in PHP. It is my first one (in PHP). I have done them in .NET before with WSDL.

There is no requirement for it to be SOAP or have any other protocol. In fact I will be writing the javascript/ajax code that will call the web service.

From what I can tell, it's this easy...I can just make a PHP script that is exposed to the world, call that file's url with url parameters, and then that PHP script returns the data in an XML format I am expecting, and prest-o-change-o, I have a PHP web service? Is it that easy???

If the answer is yes, are there any recommended best practices? Things to be careful of or take into consideration that I might not have thought of?

Thanks for humoring a PHP noob...

Comment: What's the downvote for? I am asking a legitimate question aren't I?

Comment: Well, it seems you ask only for the answer 'Yes'.

Comment: Ok, edited for a more meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is that easy. PHP is already there for the client/server stuff.
I wouldn't make it SOAP anyway, but I would JSON from it, and let it communicate in a RESTful manner.

JSON is easy too in PHP. Just create an object that contains all the data you want to return in the structure in which you want to return it. This data-object can then be serialized using `json_encode`. The JSON will be easy to use from Javascript.

Comment: Depending on your needs. OAuth is a common choice. http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what you mean "JSON from it"...also, when you say "create an object", do you mean create an object in PHP? Then serialize it and send it to the caller?

Comment: Haha. Ok thanks. I have just realized too that I'm actually not sending anything back...the call to the web service is simple to update a field in a table in a database. So I don't need to send anything back.

Comment: A status code and maybe a confirmation or error message might come in handy. ;)